# How I can use param in url without creating table in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, ruby-grape

I have a controller that works without a table in the database.
At the moment, there is an action index that performs a request to the api from which it performs the action. Route looks like `/car_collector`.

And my question is how to create a route `/car_collector/:id/edit` without creating table in database.

Just creating a route `get '/car_collector/:id/edit', to: 'car_collector#edit', as: 'edit_doc_collector', param: :id` an error is generated `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::CarCollectorController#edit`

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` -- is it full error message? May be you have notexecuted migrations for example?

Comment: @mechnicov
Migration is not needed here, since we do not have a table for this controller

Mysql2::Error: Table 'cars_core_dev.car_collectors' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `car_collectors`

Comment: Rails raises such exception if app have not-executed migrations -- it is one of the reason. Does this error appear only on edit path? If yes, how this action looks? Do you have some before filters in this controller?

Comment: @mechnicov All migrations are done, there are no filters before. I myself do not understand why this happens. I found one case on the Internet, and everything is ok there, I don’t know why it doesn’t work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :car_collector, only: :edit
```

That's it, you don't need do sometning extra

After that just go to `/car_collector/1/edit`, `/car_collector/2/edit` etc.

Default param will be as `params[:id]`

Comment: I found another way, but thank you for your time